# Smoothing pixel-by-pixel drawing in Processing

Tags: graphics, drawing, processing

I picked up Processing today, and wrote a program to generate a double slit interference pattern. After tweaking with the values a little, it works, but the pattern generated is fuzzier than what is possible in some other programs. Here's a screenshot:

[image: interference pattern]

As you can see, the fringes are not as smooth at the edges as I believe is possible. I expect them to look like [this](http://www.a-levelphysicstutor.com/images/quantum/int-fringes.JPG) or [this](http://www.one-school.net/Malaysia/UniversityandCollege/SPM/Workbook/Physics/f5chp1/quizimage/interference_green.png).

This is my code:

```java
// All quantities in mm

float slit_separation = 0.005;
float screen_dist = 50;
float wavelength = 5e-4f;

PVector slit1, slit2;

float scale = 1e+1f;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 1);
  noLoop();
  background(255);

  slit_separation *= scale;
  screen_dist *= scale;
  wavelength *= scale;

  slit1 = new PVector(-slit_separation / 2, 0, -screen_dist);
  slit2 = new PVector(slit_separation / 2, 0, -screen_dist);
}

void draw() {
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  for (float x = -width / 2; x < width / 2; x++) {
    for (float y = -height / 2; y < height / 2; y++) {
      PVector pos = new PVector(x, y, 0);
      float path_diff = abs(PVector.sub(slit1, pos).mag() - PVector.sub(slit2, pos).mag());
      float parameter = map(path_diff % wavelength, 0, wavelength, 0, 2 * PI);
      stroke(100, 100, pow(cos(parameter), 2));
      point(x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

My code is mathematically correct, so I am wondering if there's something wrong I am doing in transforming the physical values to pixels on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking- what exactly do you expect it to look like? Would it be possible to narrow this down to a single line that's misbehaving instead of the nested for loop?

But just taking a guess at what you're talking about: keep in mind that Processing enables anti-aliasing by default. To disable it, you have to call the [`noSmooth()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/noSmooth_.html) function. You can call it in your `setup()` function:

```java
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  noSmooth();
  //rest of your code
```

It's pretty obvious if you compare them side-by-side:

[image]

If that's not what you're talking about, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just one or two lines instead of a nested for loop. It would also be helpful to include a mockup of what you'd expect versus what you're getting. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for attempting an answer. I expect the transition between the bright and the dark fringes to be smoother, like a dithered gradient, and that would be the expected result. Unfortunately, the problem cannot be narrowed down to a particular line of code, but if I were to guess, I'd focus my attention on the last three lines. Let me update my question with an expected result.

Comment: @duci9y When I said "line", I didn't mean "line of code" - I meant a single drawn line. In your case, maybe a single drawn point?

Comment: I am not sure if drawing a single line or a point would make the problem apparent, since the problem is apparent only when a bigger area is drawn. And I believe my code is an MCVE, the nested for loops don't reduce readability/reproducibility and are necessary for the program to function.

Comment: @duci9y I wish you the best of luck, I'm just not sure what you're asking. That's why I'm asking for a smaller example. Hopefully somebody comes along who is more familiar with what you're asking.